# Digital Watermarking: Blind detection with linear correlation

Tags: security, watermark, digital

I'm trying to understand how a blind detection (detection without cover work) works, by applying linear correlation.
This is my understand so far:

Embedding (one-bit):

1. we generate a reference pattern `w_r` by using watermarking key
2. `W_m`:we multiply `w_r` with an strength factor `a` and take the negative values if we want to embedd a zero bit.
3. Then: `C = C_0 + W_m + N`,where `N` is noise

Blind detection (found in literature):

1. We need to calculate the linear correlation between `w_r` and `C`, to detect the appearance of `w_r` in `C`. Linear correlation in genereal is the normalizez scalar product = `1/(j*i) *C*w_r`
2. `C` consists of `C_0*w_r + W_m*w_r + w_*r*N`. It is said that, because the left and the right term is probably small, but `W_m*w_r` has large magnitude, therefore `LC(C,w_r) = +-a * |w_r|^2/(ji)`

This makes no sense to me. Why should we  only consider `+-a * |w_r|^2/(ji)` for detecting watermarks, without using `C` ?. This term `LC(C,w_r) = +-a * |w_r|^2/(ji)` is independent from `C`?

Or does this only explain why we can say that low linear correlation corresponds to zero-bit and high value to one-bit and we just compute `LC(C,w_r)` like we usually do by using the scalar product?

Thanks!